# Has anyone implemented a Java ftp client on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ftp

I saw comments that passive ftp should be possible now that [GAE supports sockets](http://googleappengine.blogspot.se/2013/04/app-engine-177-released.html). I'm wondering if anyone got this working. Thanks!

Added:  I am trying with org.apache.commons.net.ftp but it depends on javax.net.ServerSocketFactory which is banned on GAE

Comment: I added a comment about this.

Comment: You need to try it with the appengine sockets just like you said in your question.

Comment: According to the spec "App Engine supports regular outbound Java sockets such as java.net.Socket and java.net.DatagramSocket".  Now we just need to find a Java ftp client which utilizes these libraries and doesn't depend on javax.net.ServerSocketFactory.  I'm hoping someone out there has had an opportunity to get this working.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Did you get any solution for your problem? Struck with same problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with ftp4j which seems to work on GAE:

http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/

Answer (score -2):

You can use the apache client if you put it into passive mode.  Just do the following:

```
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    client.connect(FTP_HOST);
    client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

Then it won't call ServerSocketFactory, and life should be good!

Comment: This doesn't work for me (with GAE 1.9.1 and Apache Commons Net 3.3), for the exception "`javax.net.ServerSocketFactory` is a restricted class" already occurs in the call `new FTPClient()`.

Comment: I actually wound up taking the Apache source code and ripping out the ServerSocketFactory calls.  Thought it would work without that, though.